# How to decode url to path in python, django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, url, path

Hi I need to convert url to path, what i got is this url as bellow:

```
url = u'/static/media/uploads/gallery/Marrakech%2C%20Morocco_be3Ij2N.jpg'
```

and what to be looked something like this:

```
path = u'/static/media/uploads/gallery/Marrakech, Morocco_be3Ij2N.jpg'
```

thx.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`urllib.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) to decode `%`-encoded string:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> url = u'/static/media/uploads/gallery/Marrakech%2C%20Morocco_be3Ij2N.jpg'
>>> urllib.unquote(url)
u'/static/media/uploads/gallery/Marrakech, Morocco_be3Ij2N.jpg'
```

Using [`urllib.quote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) or [`urllib.quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus), you can get back:

```
>>> urllib.quote(u'/static/media/uploads/gallery/Marrakech, Morocco_be3Ij2N.jpg')
'/static/media/uploads/gallery/Marrakech%2C%20Morocco_be3Ij2N.jpg'
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3 this is in the module `urllib.parse`.

Comment: @Humphrey, The question is tagged `python-2.7`.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using **Python3** you can write

```
urllib.parse.unquote(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

with **python 3.9**  and  **django 3.2** :

### Solution 1 :

```
import urllib
urllib.parse.unquote(url)
```

### Solution 2 :

```
from django.utils.encoding import uri_to_iri
uri_to_iri(url)
```