# Django matching query does not exist in production environment

Tags: python, django

I am having problems in production with my django project. It raises 'Matching query does not exist'. In my localhost works perfect, the error is only in my server.

The line with the error is a query

```
sub_obj = Sub.objects.get(name=name)
```

I cannot access the model by 'id' in this case because the view gets that parameter from the template via href:

```
<a href="/pr/sub/{{s.name}}">{{s.name}}</a>
```

This error occurs when the name has blank spaces, for example name='My Name'. Can this have something to do with the server ? Is possible to be getting this error with parameters separated by blanks ? or could be something else ?

The url for this view is

```
url(r'^pr/sub/(?P<nname>.*)', show_only_sub),
```

Comment: Is `nname` spelled properly?

Comment: I've updated with url, the issue is only in my server ( works fine locally ), and it has something to do with query with blankspace.

Comment: Perhaps this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120951/how-can-i-normalize-a-url-in-python can help you, but I would suggest to you that use a `slug` to use on the URLs, instead of the flat name.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces in the name can cause problems. Try urlencoding the name inside the href.

```
<a href="/pr/sub/{{s.name|urlencode}}">{{s.name}}</a>
```

Comment: I've added that but I still get the error. name = 'my%20name'

Comment: You'll have to unencode it. Take a look at here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26488773/4024523

Comment: Solved adding an slug. However I don't know why I wasnt getting the error in my local server. Thanks all