# Nginx + Django - 404 not found when I try to open files with non-ASCII characters

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have problem with my app (Django + Gunicorn + Nginx) running on Docker.
I'm using X-Accel-Redirect header to serve protected files.
Serving files with only ASCII characters works fine but when I'm trying to reach files like książka.pdf I'm getting 404. I'v checked media dir and file książka.pdf exist.

In browser developer tools I can see that request is converted from /media/książka.pdf to /media/ksi%C4%85%C5%BCka.pdf

nginx.conf

```
      charset utf-8;

      location /protected_media/ {
          alias /var/media/;
          internal;

      }
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def protected_serve(request, path):
    response = HttpResponse()
    response['Content-Type']=""
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/protected_media/' + path 
    return response
```

Have anyone idea how to deal with filenames with non-ASCII characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decode url to path in python, django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488708/how-to-decode-url-to-path-in-python-django)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with path. Solution was here:
[Convert an IRI path to URI before setting as NGINX header](https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/commit/b8e20485049fa92a796d5b65fb1a577ef52a52a5)

> NGINX does not support non-ASCII characters in the header, so we need
> convert the IRI path to URI so it's compatible with what NGINX expects
> as the header value.

Final code for views:

```
from django.utils.encoding import iri_to_uri

@login_required
def protected_serve(request, path):

  x_accel_redirect = iri_to_uri(path)
  response = HttpResponse()
  response['Content-Type']=""
  response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/protected_media/' + x_accel_redirect 
  return response
```

Comment: Perfect, that was it!